# SQL Server query not working properly

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like below, but `ShowRoomName` and `UnitName`are not shown in the result. How can I solve it?

```
SELECT A.ShowRoomId
       , Sum(B.BasicAmount) AS TotalBasic
       , Sum(B.HouseAmount) AS TotalHouseAmount
       , Sum(B.MedicaleAmount) AS TotalMedicaleAmount
       , Sum(B.ConvenceAmount) AS TotalConvenceAmount
       , Sum(B.PhoneBillAmount) AS TotalPhoneBillAmount
       , Sum(B.DirectorRemuneration) AS TotalDirectorRemuneration
       , Sum(B.OthersAmount) AS TotalOthersAmount
FROM   Employees A
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   EmployeeBasics B
                    WHERE  ( A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID )
                    ORDER  BY B.BasicUpdateDate DESC) AS B
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT ShowRoomId
                           , ShowRoomName
                           , UnitId
                    FROM   dbo.ShowRooms C
                    WHERE  A.ShowRoomId = C.ShowRoomId) AS C
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT UnitId
                           , UnitName
                    FROM   dbo.Units D
                    WHERE  C.UnitId = D.UnitId) AS D
GROUP  BY A.SHowRoomId
```

Comment: Of course those columns aren't showing, they aren't in the list of columns in the select statement. Why are you using OUTER APPLY here instead of joins?

Answer (score 0):

- use a more descriptive title when you ask a question. query not
  working describes basically 99% of all questions.
- your unit name and
  showroomname dont appear because you dont select them...

Comment: maybe then you should use a left join instead of outer apply then? i'm not seeing anything in the logic to suggest why you are using outer apply instead of joins.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want something like this. Notice I changed your aliases into something meaningful. Using A, B, C is a bad habit for aliases. It is challenging to maintain code like that.

```
SELECT e.ShowRoomId
    , Sum(eb.BasicAmount) AS TotalBasic
    , Sum(eb.HouseAmount) AS TotalHouseAmount
    , Sum(eb.MedicaleAmount) AS TotalMedicaleAmount
    , Sum(eb.ConvenceAmount) AS TotalConvenceAmount
    , Sum(eb.PhoneBillAmount) AS TotalPhoneBillAmount
    , Sum(eb.DirectorRemuneration) AS TotalDirectorRemuneration
    , Sum(eb.OthersAmount) AS TotalOthersAmount
    , sr.ShowRoomName
    , u.UnitName
FROM Employees e
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM EmployeeBasics eb1
    WHERE e.EmployeeID = eb1.EmployeeID
    ORDER BY eb1.BasicUpdateDate DESC
) AS eb
LEFT JOIN ShowRooms sr ON sr.ShowRoomId = e.ShowRoomId
LEFT JOIN Units u ON u.UnitID = sr.UnitID
GROUP BY e.SHowRoomId
    , sr.ShowRoomName
    , u.UnitName
```